# Allow access to only login page in directory apache

Tags: apache2

I have password protected my webpage in Linux Mint by using mod_auth_form in apache2 with the configuration in /etc/apache2/apache2.conf:

```
<Directory "/var/www/html">
    AuthFormProvider file
    AuthType form
    AuthName "Reserved Area"
    Session On
    SessionCookieName session path=/
    require valid-user

    AuthFormLoginRequiredLocation "http://localhost/login.php"
    # This is the login page
    ErrorDocument 401 /login.php

    # This is the file containing users login data
    AuthUserFile /var/www/html/users/users
</Directory>
```

When an unauthorized user tries to access something on the webpage he will be redirected to the login page "login.php", however he won't have access to this page either so I tried adding:

```
<Location /var/www/html/login.php>
 Order Allow,Deny
 Allow from all
</Location>
```

But the problem remains and it just tries to redirect to the login page infinitely. What would enable a user to access only the login page but not anything else on the site?

Answer (score 1):

I found that if I replaced

```
<Location /var/www/html/login.php>
 Order Allow,Deny
 Allow from all
</Location>
```

with

```
<Directory /var/www/html/login>
    Options Indexes 
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

and added a folder `/var/www/html/login` where I placed everything that had to do with the login page it started working. I never figured out why Location didn't work to give access to the `login.php` file.

I also removed the line
`AuthFormLoginRequiredLocation "http://localhost/login.php`
as it wasn't needed.

The line:

```
ErrorDocument 401 /login.php
```

was also changed to:

```
ErrorDocument 401 /login/login.php
```